# Example of a Riemann integrable function which is not a simple function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, examples-counterexamples

I'm looking for an example of a Riemann integrable function which isn't simple?

I know that all simple functions $f: I \rightarrow E $ ( where $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an interval and $E$ is a Banach space) are Riemann integrable but the inclusion is strict and I don't know where to look for a not-simple but Riemann integrable function.

Could you help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple function is defined as a finite linear combination of characteristic functions. However,

$$f(x)=x$$ 
defined on $[a,b]$ and zero otherwise,
is not a characteristic function but it is Riemann integrable (in fact on all of $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f dx = \int_a^b x dx= \frac{x^2}{2}|_a^b = .5 (b^2-a^2)$

Comment: Here $E=\mathbb{R}$ which is clearly a Banach because the completeness of the real numbers (from undergraduate analysis) and the norm is the usual absolute value.  $I=[a,b]$ here.

Comment: Thank you. I should've thought of that :)